# Bootbox Callback Keep Cached Page

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, bootbox

I have functionality like this:

```
bootbox.confirm({
        message: "Delete?",
        buttons: {
            confirm: {
                label: 'Yes',
                className: 'btn-success'
            },
            cancel: {
                label: 'No',
                className: 'btn-danger'
            }
        },
        callback: function (result) {
            if (result == true) {
                $.ajax({
                    type: 'Post',
                    data: { 'employeeId': $("#Id").val(), 'Id': Id },
                    datatype: 'json',
                    url: '/EmployeeInsuranceWorkRecords/DeleteEmployeeWorkRecord',
                    success: function (data) {
                        var url = '/Employee/Profile?employeeId=' + $("#employeeId").val();
                        //document.location.reload(true); not work
                        //window.location.href = url; not work
                        //rand number does not works as well
                    },
                    error: function (xhr) {
                        errorHandler(xhr);
                    },
                    complete: function () {
                        unblockPage();
                    }
                });
            }

        }
    });
```

When I received success from ajax request, the page redirected to the specified page but it keeps old data(table records) and doesn't refresh the page actually, Then I had to refresh again to see functionally effect(like CRUD).

It keeps a cached version for the first redirect. on the second refresh page updated successfully.  How can I change the code to refresh the page and get ajax success response without any cache existence?

Thanks

Comment: I don't see a question? I only see a statement.

Comment: Have you tried the `cache : false` option in your ajax setup?

Comment: @Refilon yes I did